# How to launch a function on another (IO) thread only one time (with coroutines)?

Tags: android, runnable, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-coroutines

I am using nisrulz QReader. As in the examples

```
qrEader = new QREader.Builder(this, mySurfaceView, new QRDataListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDetected(final String data) {
     //   Log.d("QREader", "Value : " + data);
        text.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSomething(data);
            }
        });
    }
}).facing(QREader.BACK_CAM)
        .enableAutofocus(true)
        .height(mySurfaceView.getHeight())
        .width(mySurfaceView.getWidth())
        .build();
```

they have a text which is a TextView, thus making post(Runnable) possible. I do not have any views and I do not want to add..

How can I run `doSomething(data)` only one time on another thread?

EDIT:
I tried to convert Java example code to Kotlin:

```
qreader = QREader.Builder(view.context, surface_view, QRDataListener { data ->
    myTextView.post {
        doSomething(data)
    }
})
.facing(QREader.BACK_CAM)
.enableAutofocus(true)
.height(surface_view.height)
.width(surface_view.width)
.build()
```

Comment: Java doesn't have coroutines. m You can create a Thread, and start it, which is proabbly what you want.  I'm answering in HJava because this doesn't look like Kotlin code-  I don't think it uses the new keyword at all.

Comment: @GabeSechan That was just an example. I use that lib in my Kotlibn project. Unfortunately `Handler().post{}...` won't work.